# Is $F:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ invertible?

Tags: inverse-function, jacobian

Let $F:\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$ where $n \neq m$. I'm confused as to whether this map can be invertible or not.

The Inverse Function Theorem ensures the existence of a local inverse provided that the Jacobian determinant is non-zero. But clearly this is only defined for maps between vector spaces of the same dimension.

So in the case where $n \neq m$ the Inverse Function Theorem says nothing. Does this necessarily mean that the map can't be invertible?

Comment: Have you considered the case when $F$ is a linear map?

Comment: @Jack Yes. So if $F$ is linear then the two spaces are isomorphic if and only if they have the same dimension. That is, there exists a bijective linear map between them if and only if they have the same dimension. I'm just unsure about when $F$ is not linear.

Comment: Inverse Function Theorem give us a sufficient condition about a $C^1$ function to conclude that it is a local diffeomorphism. Have you considered the case when $F$ is any function? (No assumption about continuity or differentiability)

Comment: Some maps are invertible, some are not. What is your question?

Comment: @AlexProvost For linear maps, if they are between spaces of different dimension then they are not invertible. Is the same true for non linear maps?

Comment: @user485139 There exist bijections between $R^n$ and $R^m$ for all $n,m \geq 1$. Of course as soon as you add in more restrictive conditions such as continuity or linearity, this goes down the drain.